# problem with uitableview when return

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have viewcontroller with table view that when i click on a cell i go in the navigation to another view controller with another tableview.

i try to use the viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear in the first viewcontroller, that when i back to this viewcontroller from the second viewcontroller i will enter one of this method.

the problem is that he didn't enter this method when i return to this viewcontroller.

this is how i enter the second view controller:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        ProfileViewController2 *tmp = [[ProfileViewController2 alloc]initWithType:indexPath.row string:[self.array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:tmp animated:YES];
        [tmp release];
        [self.mytableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` should get called. What were you trying to do in `viewWillAppear:` and also how did you return to the first view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are notoriously shaky on iOS.

If you are working with `UITableView`s we always put the code we need to run before the table gets loaded into the

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

function. It's a slight hack but works very well as this is the first function out of the UITableViewDataSource protocol called.

Alternatively, you can call

```
    [tmp viewDidAppear];
```

After pushing the view controller and before releasing `tmp` to force the function being called.